# bincount in Numpypy

Tags: python, numpy, pypy

I have a project that makes a heavy use of the Numpy function [bincount](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html). Now I would like to  use **pypy** to increment the performance. Unfortunately as reported in the [numpypy status page](http://buildbot.pypy.org/numpy-status/latest.html) there is still no support for the bincount function.

So my questions are:

1. Is there an alternative function as fast as bincount that can be implemented with numpypy? I look at [histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) but it is way too slower and I think using it would defeat the advantages of using pypy. Here's the proof:

   *Numpy*

   ```
   timeit.timeit("np.bincount(x)", setup="import numpy as np; x = np.array([0] * 20 + [1] * 30)")
   0.8197031021118164
   ```

   *Numpypy*

   ```
   timeit.timeit("np.histogram(x)", setup="import numpy as np; x = np.array([0] * 20 + [1] * 30)")
   12.335555076599121
   ```
2. I happily see that the numpypy development is very active. So as my project deadline is within a month are there any chances that bincount is going to be implemented within such date?

Comment: within a month?  Unlikely unless you do it yourself ...

Comment: FWIW, if you have loops that can't be vectorized, I've found in the past that it often takes less time to mark up the code for cython than it does to get it to work using the subset of implemented numpypy.  [There will come a point when that may change as more and more gets implemented, of course; I'm only saying I haven't happened to hit that point yet in a project.]  You might even have better luck with numba-- it doesn't always help, but it doesn't take too long to find out.

Comment: `(x[:, None] == np.unique(x)).sum(0)` is slower than `bincount`, but 3x faster than `histogram`.  It's a tiny bit faster with `einsum` but that's not available in `numpypy` either.

Comment: honestly, einsum isn't faster, it is slower on newer numpy versions.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement bincount by doing something like:

```
def bincount(x):
    result = np.zeros(x.max() + 1, int)
    for i in x:
        result[i] += 1
```

You'd have to profile it to know for sure, but because of pypy's jit compiler this should actually be very fast, even if it's not as fast as a pure c implementation. If you try it, I'd like to know how it goes.